# Question mark folder when booting after removing boot camp. Stuck on repair process

Tags: macos, terminal, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I was trying removing boot camp from my MacBook Pro (ME294LL/A) that was running macOS Mojave. I had some trouble getting disk utility to remove the old windows partition and incorporate the old space into my main Mac partition, and I probably made a mistake in there somewhere. My Mac ran just fine until it was shut down and now when I boot in up, I get the flashing question mark folder.

I tried to follow this article from Apple: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204323

I was able to use internet recovery to get to disk utility and terminal and I haven’t been able to repair my startup disk. Here’s that I get when I try to verify the disk:
[image]
The partition map needs to be repaired because there’s a problem with the EFI system partition’s file system.

And this is what I get when I try to repair it:
[image]
Unrecognized file system.

I tried to follow some other instructions from people that appeared to have a similar problem, and this is what I get when I run the following commands in Terminal:
[image]

I think there’s something with repairing the partition table for the startup disk, but I can’t figure out what command I need to run to fix it. Or maybe I’m getting this confused and that’s not the problem at all.

I don’t have a time machine backup of my system - otherwise I’d just restore to that. If there’s a way to copy off the files from my Mac (maybe from terminal?) and just reinstall the OS, I could do that too. But I’d prefer to fix the startup disk and just boot back into it if I can. Any ideas on what I’m missing?

Comment: That looks like an older version of Disk Utility, so it won't know how to handle the APFS filesystem that Mojave uses. Try starting up with Command-Option-R, which should get the newest version of the Recovery environment (including Disk Utility) that'll work on your Mac (see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)). Then open Terminal, run `sw_vers`, and make sure it's at least 10.14 (Mojave) so you have a new enough version. *Then* try Disk Utility and see if it can fix things.

Comment: Try holding down the option key when the Mac first starts up. When the Mac Startup Manager icons appear, hold down the control key and select macOS.

Comment: When I do Command+Option+R, It errors out saying “apple.com/support” & “-5101F”. Any ideas on what I’m doing wrong? I’ve tried connecting to multiple internet connections with the same result each time.

Comment: I found two relevant-looking discussions: [here](https://appuals.com/error-5010f-when-reinstalling-os-x-via-internet-recovery/) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4400711). I'd try resetting NVRAM first (restart holding Comand+Option+P+R keys), then try Command+Option+R again. If that doesn't work, your Internet connection may not be consistent enough; is there another you can try using?